# ViewDidLoad not the right command

Tags: iphone

I can't seem to find what I am looking for in the Apple documentation.  I am saving a simple string to an NSUserDefaults location and I want it to load that string into a UITextField in a view that I have already created.  Everything is working great with the data persistence (it is saving and loading correctly) but it will only load the information on viewDidLoad.  The user edits the field in a modal view so when I call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated, the view does not register the updated UITextField because viewDidLoad is not being called for the first time.  (hope I am explaining this coherently enough - i apologize)

How can I have it update that UITextField immediately so the user can see their updated field?  I don't think viewDidAppear is the correct place but I can't figure out where to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or do it in the modal view before you dismiss it by calling the modal views parent (which should be the controller for the textField) and editing it there

In your Modal View Controller before you dismiss it:

```
self.parentViewController.myTextField.text = editingTextField.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about -viewWillAppearAnimated:(BOOL)animated, instead of -viewDidLoad?

Comment: This works provided it can't change while the view is on-screen. A more general approach is NSNotifications or key-value observing, but that's more work to set up.

Comment: I can't find viewWillAppearAnimated anywhere.  I have tried viewWillAppear but that doesn't seem to work because it is just releasing the modal view.  If there was just something I could call immediately before releasing the modal view - but I'm not sure how to do that.